# Displaying double as integer in textfield using action listener

Tags: java, actionlistener, textfield, windowbuilder

Method for displaying number on button

```
class JNumberBtnClick implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JNumberButton sender= (JNumberButton)arg0.getSource();

        textField_1.setText(textField_1.getText()+sender.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Button

```
JNumberButton btnNewButton = new JNumberButton(1.0);
btnNewButton.addActionListener(btnClickEvent);
btnNewButton.setNumber(1.0);
btnNewButton.setBounds(20, 52, 89, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

JNumberButton class

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class JNumberButton extends JButton {

double number;

public JNumberButton(double number) {
    super(Double.toString(number));
    this.number=number;
}

public double getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(double number) {
    this.number=number;
    setText(Integer.toString((int)number));
}
}
```

This is how it looks like when I use the button.

[image: Screenshot]

And the question what do I have to do to make it display 1 instead of 1.0? I want it to stay as double, but I want it to be displayed as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class:

```
String number = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1.0);
```

The result will be `1`.

Alternatively you can use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) if you want to be able to use a different format:

```
String number = new DecimalFormat().format(1.0);
```

You can pass a pattern to the constructor if you want.

Both methods also display double values if needed. If you want to display only integers you can use the pattern `#`. This will cause all doubles to be rounded to an integer:

```
String number = new DecimalFormat("#").format(1.3);
```

The result will be `1`.

The complete `JNumberButton` would look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class JNumberButton extends JButton {
    private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");
    private double number;

    public JNumberButton(double number) {
        super(format.format(number));
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(double number) {
        setText(format.format(number));
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above you can adjust the format to fit your needs.

Comment: Ok, but i'm not sure how to use it in my situation. I can't use it in JNumberButton class because it's just declaration and constructor (and get and set), and i don't know how to override it for specific button. Unless i can do it for all of them at once.

Comment: When i want to use it in setText() i'm getting "NumberFormat cannot be resolved or is not a field" or "Number Format cannot be resolved" depending where i type it inside setText().

Comment: I have realized i done something very stupid. I cannot just use it with setText because it's method for all buttons, not specific 1.0 button. I have more of these buttons in the program, i'm just trying to solve it on example.

Comment: I have found somewhere that i can use that structure in super, but it gives me error "DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Yeah i have realized now it might be the problem, but it should say that something is missing, for unknown reason it didn't show anything beside error. Anyway now there are no errors, but still no difference - text field still shows 1.0 instead of 1.

Comment: Hmm yes thats different, but still the same effect (1.0 instead of 1). I think previous one was identical to new one, in older solution i just had "new" inside "super" instead of using "static final".

Comment: It is. Maybe it's matter of created buttons? But i haven't changed anything (you can see code in the main post).

Comment: Seems like it. How to make it work then? I'm trying to put this format thingy into getNumber() but it "cannot convert from String to double". Edit Changing public double to public String solves issue, but what if i want to keep getter as double? Unless it's impossible.